# Accessing Database Items in a Timer

Tags: events

We are experiencing some problems when accessing items using a Timer which is not consistent for all items. We have the following code:

```
        var database =Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(indexItem.TargetDatabase);
        var item = database.GetItem(indexItem.Id, indexItem.Language);

        if(item == null)
        {
            Diagnostics(indexItem.WithDiagnostics, "Item missing in database {0}:{1}:{2}", indexItem.TargetDatabase, indexItem.Id, indexItem.Language);

        }
```

For the item **/sitecore/content/site/home** it works, however for the item **/sitecore/content/site/home/page1** it fails. This is the same if we access master or web.

Testing the above code in a webpage it works fine for both items on master and web, it just seems to be on the timer event that it fails.

The failure is consistent for each item, i.e. it always fails or it always succeeds.

The time is implemented as follows:

```
            _processingTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(processingInterval);
            _processingTimer.Elapsed += (obj, args) => ProcessQueue(queueStartParams);
            _processingTimer.AutoReset = true;
            _processingTimer.Start();
```

Anyone know of any issues related to threading and events in SC?

Comment: How do you implement the Timer? Can you please share it?

Comment: added timer code

Comment: Instead of using a Timer, would it not preferable to make use of a sitecore schedule agent which runs based on the interval you need?

Comment: Have you tried with SecurityDisabler?

Comment: I was thinking; how do you persist your Search Context here?  are you certain it isn't dropped (.Dispose()'d) at some point while the timed code runs?